# How to breakdown function in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

I have created codes for the controller js of my lightning component which uses a handler that takes the parameter value from an event:

```
checkChange: function(component, event, handler) {
    var test_Id = component.get("v.TEST_Id");

    if(condition 1){
        //some action using the test id
    }
    if(condition 2){
        //some action some action using the test id
    }
    if(condition 2){
        //some action some action using the test id
    }
}
```

how do you breakdown the codes from each if statement's action? Like, I tried creating the action from the helper js but it doesn't perform right like how i made it in the controller js. did the handler cause it?

this is quiet related to my question here [How to get parameter value from event?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239007/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-event/239008#239008)

Answer (score 2):

you can create function in helper and pass desired parameter to it. `event` could be passed as well

**helper.js**

```
({
    handleCheckChange : function(component, event){
        var test_Id = component.get("v.TEST_Id");
        // work with event in helper function
        if(condition 1){
            //some action using the test id
        }
        if(condition 2){
            //some action some action using the test id
        }
        if(condition 2){
            //some action some action using the test id
        }
    }
})
```

your controller will look like:

```
checkChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.handleCheckChange(component, event);
}
```